# usage of the verb proof

Tags: meaning

Does it sound natural to say: "I've proofed your homework and it's ok"? I'd like to say something different than I've corrected your work, or I've checked your work.

Comment: If you've graded it, you might say "I've marked".

Comment: BTW, what's wrong with "corrected"?

Comment: nothing wrong! Just fancy using a different word!

Comment: I believe the odd-sounding but grammatically correct word to use would be the verb form: 'proved' - using its old meaning of 'tested' or 'examined' - as in 'proving ground'  . . . but that sounds even less natural so . . . maybe not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use reviewed? It's a far better alternative. It's a much broader term that encompasses the various ways a teacher may examine a student's homework: checking grammar, spelling, punctuation, sentence structure, accuracy of the content, etc.

**[Review (verb)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/review)**: to go over or examine critically or deliberately

> I've reviewed your homework, and everything looks okay.

Comment: I liked 'review', thanks. I think I will 'adopt' it, at least for a little while!

Comment: If you found my response helpful, please consider accepting it :)

Comment: I don't know how to...

Comment: There should be a little check mark below the downvote button

Comment: I will probably find it on my pc. I'm currently on my phone. I'll be looking for it over the weekend. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A *proof* (noun) is [[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proof)]

> 2. *Printing*
>      A trial impression of a page, taken from type or film and used for making corrections before final printing.
>
>    2.1 A trial photographic print made for initial selection.
>
>    2.2 Each of a number of impressions from an engraved plate, especially (in commercial printing) of a limited number before the ordinary issue is printed and before an inscription or signature is added.

Using *proof* as a verb would mean *to **make** these trial prints.*

What you are doing, it seems, is ***proof-reading:*** reading through a proof or draft in order to find errors which need correction. [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proofread) has the verb as a single word, *proofread:*

> Read (printer's proofs or other written or printed material) and mark any errors.

Thus your *proofed* should actually be *proof-read*.*

---

* Unfortunately, the written form isn't very clear: this is the past participle pronounced /rɛd/.

Comment: Does "proofreading" include anything other than checking grammar, spelling and punctuation?   I don't think you would say you're proofreading algebra or chemestry homework.

Comment: @Centaurus, any work that could contain an error can be proofed or, more formally, proof-read. I don't see why that might not include algebra or chemistry work.